# simplest way to use <input type="file">

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I want to store user picture along with other attributes, I want to store path of image in database and copy of image to my desire folder,

Please help  for solution .

Comment: Stackoverflow is not "Rent-a-coder". You should put some effort into your problem and ask specific questions if you need help.

Comment: You have to be more specific. What is your main problem here?

Comment: i have got all the attributes, i am only looking for some efficient way to store image, i am confused to use blob data type, i want to store images in specific folder and there path in database

Comment: I think the best help would be to do some reading to understand what it means to use an input box of file type and how PHP handles them. Luckily there are tons of tutorials around the internet to accomplish this.  Check this out:

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @nfechner: I have not asked for the code, I only asked for the best way, your response was discouraging:-(, still thanks for your comment..

Comment: OK, the best way depends a lot on your setup. If you have a Webapplication with multiple instances, you need to put the files into the database unless you want to synchronize them between your nodes. Otherwise, just storing the file path is definitely the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) ([guide](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html))
- servlet 3.0 multipart support (if you are using servlet 3.0 compliant container)

Then use a folder outside the web application (configurable in some way) and store the path in the database.